# Python - How can I pause at thread by other thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, async-await, loading

I am confused for showing waiting message.

For my program, 
Step 1, it keep looping to show the waiting message.
Step 2, If the `trigger_file` exist, it stop the waiting message and run `main_process()`
Step 3,  After finishing `main_process`, it show the waiting message again.

I tried to use variable `waiting` to stop the waiting message but it is not working
I am not sure how to use async/await function and multithreadubg for this case.
Thank you

```
import os
import time
import threading


waiting = True
trigger_file = r'D:\Desktop\OK'



def main_process():
    print('1')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('2')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('3')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('4')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('5')

def print_waiting():   # animation of waiting
    while(waiting):
        for loading_symbol in ['|','/','-','\\','|','/','-','\\','|']:
            print('\r[INFO] Waiting for trigger... '+loading_symbol,end="")
            time.sleep(0.2)


def triggerListener():  # trigger a function if the file exist
    while(True):
        if os.path.exists(trigger_file):
            global waiting
            waiting=False
            print('\n[INFO] main process start')
            main_process()
            waiting=True





if __name__ == "__main__":
    # creating thread
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=print_waiting)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=triggerListener)
  
    # starting thread 1
    t1.start()
    # starting thread 2
    t2.start()
  
    # wait until thread 1 is completely executed
    t1.join()
    # wait until thread 2 is completely executed
    t2.join()
  
    # both threads completely executed
    print("Done!")
```

Expected Output:

```
[INFO] Waiting for trigger... -
[INFO] main process start
1
2
3
4
5
[INFO] Waiting for trigger... -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I use `threading.Lock` to solve the problem. `acquire` the lock and `release` the lock after finishing the function.

```
class Print_waiting(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,lock):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.running = True
        self.lock = lock

    def run(self):   # animation of waiting
        while self.running:
            for loading_symbol in ['|','/','-','\\','|','/','-','\\','|']:
                self.lock.acquire()
                print('\r[INFO] Waiting for trigger... '+loading_symbol,end="")
                self.lock.release()
                time.sleep(0.2)

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
    


class TriggerListener(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,lock):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.running = True
        self.lock = lock  # for mutex

    def run(self):   # trigger a function if the file exist
        while(self.running):
            if os.path.exists(trigger_file):
                self.lock.acquire()
                print('\n[INFO] main process start')
                Program.main()
                self.lock.release()

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False




if __name__ == "__main__":
    lock = threading.Lock()
    waiting_anime = Print_waiting(lock)
    Trigger_RPA = TriggerListener(lock)

    Trigger_RPA.start()
    waiting_anime.start()

    Trigger_RPA.join()
    waiting_anime.join()
```